# login_check ClassNotFound after install Sonata\CacheBundle

Tags: symfony, orm, fosuserbundle

I installed SonataCacheBundle (dev-master), because it is needed by e-commerce bundle.

After that, when user attempts to login (via route **/login** or **admin/login**), system prints me out error:

*Attempted to load class "DoctrineORMListener" from namespace "Sonata\CacheBundle\Invalidation".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Sonata\Cache\Invalidation\DoctrineORMListener"?*

That happens after user input username and password and click the button and URL is **/login_check**.

If I ignore that and after that error go to **/admin**, user is successfully signed. There is some problem with **/login_check**

I use symfony 3.4, fosuserbundle 2.1 and sonata-project/user-bundle 4.1.

Did I miss something when install CacheBundle?

Comment: I solve that problem with installing "sonata-project/cache": "1.x-dev" and "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.4"